# How do i add a PATH variable in the user variables of the environment variables?

Tags: python

I have a path variable in the system variables but how do i add a path variable in the user variables section since i don't have any at the moment.
If there isn't a path variable  in the user variables will it affect in any way?
How much will values of the path variables differ from the one in environment variables to the one in user variables if there is only one user present?

Answer (score 0):

to add a new variable in users variable

1. click one new button below the user variables.

2.Then a pop window will appear asking you to type new variable name and its value, click ok after entering name and value.

Thats how you can add a new variable in user variables.
You should have a path variable in user variables also because ,for example while installing python you have a choice to add python path to variables here the path will be added in user variable 'path'.